# Names referred to as words

Tags: names

Style guides seem to agree that words referred to as words should be italicized or set in quotes. So:

- The term *critical mass* is...

The CMOS 17th adds that proper nouns used as words are usually set in roman, giving this example:

- You rarely see iPhone with a capital *i*. (Section 7.63)

I'm wondering more generally about references to names. Does it make sense to leave all the following names in roman?

- Two men, both named Sam, were...
- His name was Sam.
- Call me Ishmael.
- The girl called herself Peggy, though her name was Margaret.
- She referred to the drink as a Manhattan Project and ordered two.

Comment: What do you mean by "roman"? Please cite the sources you mention. Is this a proof-reading question?

Comment: By "roman" I mean regular type, that is, type that is not set in italics, bold, or small caps. It's not a proof-reading question. It's a question about styling names referred to as names. The third example is from Herman Melville's _Moby-Dick or The Whale_ (Penguin 1992), page 3.  The others are invented for the purpose of illustration in this question.

Comment: I don't think any of the last five examples need any kind of emphasis.

Comment: A name is just that, a name, not a word used as a word, as in “English _smart_ and German _Schmerz_ ‘pain’ are cognates.”

Comment: A name can be a word used as a word, just as is illustrated in the example regarding _term_, above. Accordingly, there's a difference between "Bill took a cab" and "The man named Bill took a cab. Clearly, "His name, Bill, is a common one" is an example of a word referred to as a word. "His name is Bill" -- maybe not?

Comment: What’s the Question here, please?
When ”Style guides seem to agree words referred to as words should be italicized or set in quotes”, what does that mean? To me, it’s nonsense. Anyone else?
Can you explain what “The term critical mass…” means to you, or drop tt, please?

When CMOS 17th adds that proper nouns used as words are set in Roman - note that capital “R”?-  how does that relate to anything else?

Did you realise you not just rarely, but never correctly see iPhone with a capital “I” because “iPhone” is a trade-mark; a proprietary term?

Comment: A word referred to as a word, or a term referred to as a term, is like the term _critical mass_ in this example:

The term _critical mass_ is...

That is, the writer is referring to "critical mass" as a **term** rather than using it in an ordinary way, like:

The project attained critical mass on Tuesday.

My question, is whether names when referred to as names should be set apart -- in italics or within quotation marks.

Comment: The CMOS, 17th sec 7.63 says that "Proper nouns used as words are usually set in roman" -- and that's opposed to the usual rule it states for styling words as words, which it says should be done by setting them in italics or with quotation marks.

I am wondering whether this rule is accepted and whether it applies to all instances of referring to names as words. It has nothing to do with capitalization or trademarked names.

Comment: Let me try this again. If you were are talking about names, say, “English sources routinely omit the diacritical marks in _Dvořák_,” then that is a word as word. If you write “Few Americans could master the Czech pronunciation of the name Dvořák, it's no longer word as word.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the relevant distinction. In the CMOS example advising italicizing _critical_ _mass_, the reference to the term has nothing to do with its formal qualities. That said, it feels like your two examples regarding _Dvořák_ are correct. And I think Tuffy's guidance about "chance of misunderstanding" is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weather Vane and jdscoms has fair points, jdscoms.  You do need to research more fully.

Nevertheless, your question also has a point.  The use of italics or single *scare* quotes to indicate mention rather than use is a convention in the sense that it does not emerge from the rough and tumble of day to day conversation and correspondence.  The convention is observed to avoid misunderstanding or involuntary humour.

It is worth remembering that in ancient Hebrew, Greek and Latin there was no punctuation of any kind, and they managed quite well.

Proper names do not normally need this convention.  There is no need to distinguish between “My brother is George.”, and “My name is George”.  There is no chance of misunderstanding.

But you might think twice before writing “George is six letters long.”.  It is unlikely to be misunderstood.  But it does look a bit silly.  Note, though, that you do not have to use italic or scare quotes.  You could just write:  “the name George is six letters long.”.  Then we shall all know what you mean.

As for the iPhone, that is a brand name and the ‘i’ must be left untouched.

Overall, a little common sense takes us a long way.